# DLL exporting only certain templatized functions

Tags: c++

Hey all, so this seems to be a rather strange issue to me. I have a very simple templatized container class which is part of a DLL. The entire class is defined in a header file, to allow automatic template generation. Now another part of the DLL actually requests a certain template type to be generated, so the code should exist within the DLL. However, when using the object from another executable, the constructor/destructor, plus multiple other functions work, however 2 functions are not found by the linker. Following are is the code for these two functions, as well as for a working function.

```
const T** getData() const
{
    return m_data;
}

int getNumRows() const
{
    return m_nRows;
}

int getNumCols() const
{
    return m_nCols;
}
```

So the getNumRows() and getNumCols() functions are not found by the linker, however the getData() function is. Is this a common problem, do the functions need to have a templatized parameter in order to be generated?

@1 800 INFORMATION

I have exported this from the DLL via a standard macro:

```
#ifdef ACORE_EXPORTS
#define ACORE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ACORE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And at the class definition:

```
template < class T >
class ACORE_API matrix
```

Answer (score 7):

The compiler will only generate member functions that are actually called.

For instance:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{public:
    int function1()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int function2()
    {
        T t;
        t->DoSomething();
        return 0;
    }
};
```

and then later

```
MyClass<int> m;
m.function1();
```

compiles, because MyClass::function2() was never compiled.

You can force the instantiation of the entire class by doing this:

```
template class MyClass<int>;
```

In that case, every method in the class will be instantiated. In this example, you get a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you Johan, it seems very simple now hehe. I was calling the one (working) function within the DLL and it was thus generated, however not the other (non-working) functions. I was under the impression that something like MyClass<int> m; at any point, would cause the entire class to be generated for int.

Comment: Thanks... cool, this was my first time using this site. It is really well put together!

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually exporting the functions from the library? You would mention the names in the .def file, or use the `dllexport` and `dllimport` directives in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes I am, I would imagine that would be answered by the fact that some functions work. But yes I am using a dllexport/dllimport macro for this class.